# How to cache loaded swf avatars in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, swfloader

I'm using custom renderer with s:SWFLoader inside to display clients swf avatars in s:List. useVirtualLayout is "on".

When new client arrives (or leaves chat) s:List send new data to the renderers.

So SWFLoader in renderer have to load new data. And as a result we have flickering. When swf avatar disappears for second and appears again.

I've resolved this issue when all avatars was just images. I've saved content from Loader and used it as data source for s:Image.

But with swf avatars this approach does not work because after adding on stage we cannot change parent of the AVM1Movie (have not tried another version because i have to support this one too).

I've looked in SWFLoader source code and found that Loader added on stage before loading data.

Also i've tried to load swf to ByteArray and call loadBytes. But flickering still exists.

And i've tried to return Loader as a source.

So what will you recomend to do in this situation? Is swf caching possible?

Comment: we had a similar problem.  What we did to resolve the flickering was to set a handle to the user (and image swf) data and not garbage collect it.  so then the item renderers re-displayed, the item was still in memory.

Comment: Even if parent of AVM1Movie can't be changed, you can move it with Loader that loaded it.